# How can a generate a key with defined key size with a hash function with its security/internal state shorter than the key?

Tags: hash, keys, entropy, key-size

Let's suppose I took a high resolution photo full of entropy and I want to convert in a key with 2048-bits of security.

Practically all the known hash algorithms have maximum 512-bits of security.

Is there a mode/scheme to generate a 2048-bit key with a hash function with its internal state/security of 512-bits (or 256-bits maybe)?

Comment: `convert in a key 2048-bits of security`  why? what do you want to achieve?

Comment: This is really really easy, but I have to walk the dog. More later... (Hint: randomness extraction). See [Photonic Instrument](http://www.reallyreallyrandom.com/photonic/) write-up. It's exactly what you're doing.